# How to fix navbar toggler in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a navbar with bootstrap but when on the smallest screens, the navbar toggler does not align to the left of the image. It ends up over the logo. At worst I wouldn't mind it on the bottom, but ideally i would like it to place to the left of the logo.

I have tried adding containers around the elements which did not help.

```
<div class="container">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>Menu
      </button>
  <img src="images/irgLogo.jpg" class="mt-1 ml-4 img-fluid">

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
      <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="">Home</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
      <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="IRG Listings" >IRG Listings</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
      <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Property Search ">Property Search</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
      <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Communities on Candlewood Lake">Agents</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
      <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href=""  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Buyer Resources">Buying</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
      <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href=""  target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Seller Resources">Selling</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
      <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href=""  target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Contact Independent Realty Group">Contact</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can view the issue at //candlewoodlakelifestyle.com/irg
I get no error messages but the toggler refuses to exist where I want.

Comment: Was your problem solved? How?

Comment: When I remove the menu text it made it a bit better. I still am having trouble with it and decided to leave as is. For some reason I have alot of issues when creating bootstrap nav bars. And its supposed to be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this below or a more "conventional" one?

I advise to not put the navigation inside a container. If you have to make it a fluid container:

```css
.nav-item {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>Menu
          </button>
    <img src="images/irgLogo.jpg" class="mt-1 ml-4 img-fluid">

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
      <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="">Home</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
      <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="IRG Listings">IRG Listings</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
      <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Property Search ">Property Search</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
      <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Communities on Candlewood Lake">Agents</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
      <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Buyer Resources">Buying</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
      <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Seller Resources">Selling</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
      <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Contact Independent Realty Group">Contact</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Beter version:

```css
.nav-item {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {color: #fff;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>Menu
          </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarResponsive">
    <a href="#" class="logo"><svg class="d-block" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 612 612" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" focusable="false"><title>Bootstrap</title><path fill="currentColor" d="M510 8a94.3 94.3 0 0 1 94 94v408a94.3 94.3 0 0 1-94 94H102a94.3 94.3 0 0 1-94-94V102a94.3 94.3 0 0 1 94-94h408m0-8H102C45.9 0 0 45.9 0 102v408c0 56.1 45.9 102 102 102h408c56.1 0 102-45.9 102-102V102C612 45.9 566.1 0 510 0z"></path><path fill="currentColor" d="M196.77 471.5V154.43h124.15c54.27 0 91 31.64 91 79.1 0 33-24.17 63.72-54.71 69.21v1.76c43.07 5.49 70.75 35.82 70.75 78 0 55.81-40 89-107.45 89zm39.55-180.4h63.28c46.8 0 72.29-18.68 72.29-53 0-31.42-21.53-48.78-60-48.78h-75.57zm78.22 145.46c47.68 0 72.73-19.34 72.73-56s-25.93-55.37-76.46-55.37h-74.49v111.4z"></path></svg></a>
    <span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
    <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="">Home</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
    <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="IRG Listings">IRG Listings</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
    <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Property Search ">Property Search</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
    <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Communities on Candlewood Lake">Agents</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
    <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Buyer Resources">Buying</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
    <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Seller Resources">Selling</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
    <a class="nav-item mt-5 ml-4" href="" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Contact Independent Realty Group">Contact</a><span class="hidden-md"><br></span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you guys. Razvan I used the example above and it worked great. Was it because I had a container inside? I did that to center all the elements on the navbar. Now I am having trouble centering the image and links. Any ideas? I have tried setting the margin to auto with no luck.

Comment: @MikeCavallo Because of the container and because there was no `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">` rag.

Comment: Any ideas on how to center the navbar elements now?

Comment: @MikeCavallo which of the two wimples did you use?

Comment: The second 'better' one

Comment: @MikeCavallo on `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">` add the CSS class `justify-content-center`. I have edited my second snippet. Check please.

Comment: That justified the links to center but left the logo stuck to the left. tried to justify the image right with no luck. Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I added a container around the items to make it work. I tried the way above with no luck

Comment: @MikeCavallo **Move** the logo inside the <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarResponsive"> element. See my answer, **edited**.

Comment: I will be at computer later today and will give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the 'Menu' text on the button.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>Menu
</button>
```

It's adding an extra space on the button's right side. The color is set to white that's why you couldn't see it.

I attached some screenshots so you can see.

[image: Screenshot 1] [image: Screenshot2]